# Qtbase5 installation modified graphics significantly

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, fonts, qt5

I was trying to apply a patch, which has been a problem because information on this subject is very limited. I use Kubuntu 16.04 LTS, by the way.

For some reason I thought that the package to be patched should be installed. The package was `qtbase5-dev`. When this package was installed and the computer rebooted the graphics changed.

Titles in titlebars are bigger (bigger font) as well as the font in the plugins (like time and date, wifi options, etc). Chromium is now asking me to make it my default browser (although my account is still logged in). In the terminal (konsole), the cursor is 2 or 3 spaces ahead of the letters. In kate, some words do not display correctly, and the tabs have changed its horizontal spacing (luckily noticed because some sort of ascii art).

I immediately uninstall the package and rebooted with no success.

## Update 1:

I also noted that in the logon screen, the background image seems to be zoomed in, when I enter the password correctly and hit enter, the image will render ok (no zoom) and start the system with all the issues I am having. Also now I am unable to change the brightness by using the function keys, and the brightness in the energy saving window is grayed out (disabled).

## Update 2:

By now, I have been exploring more the situation, the brightness issue appears to be because of the uninstallation of the package. The laptop won't tell me the battery charge either.

Answer (score 0):

## Not so satisfying solution:

Suddenly, a big number of the issues were automatically solved by an update: the titles font in titlebars and the plugins font (like time and date, wifi options, etc) are back to normal font size. In the terminal (`konsole`), the cursor (and font) are back to normal. In `kate` (text editor), the spacing and fonts have been set back to the default monospaced font. The brightness can now be customized by means of using the function keys. The battery status can now be seen. I am unable to track what was the update that fixed everything of this, I am enclosing the update log. **"Suspend" is working now (it wasn't).**

---

**Update Log file:**

```
Start-Date: 2016-06-08  11:54:23
Install: pam-kwallet-init:amd64 (4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1, automatic), kactivitymanagerd:amd64 (5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1, automatic), libkwinglutils8:amd64 (4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1, automatic), libkf5screen7:amd64 (4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1, automatic), plasma-integration:amd64 (5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1, automatic), libkwinxrenderutils8:amd64 (4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1, automatic), libkwineffects8:amd64 (4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1, automatic)
Upgrade: init:amd64 (1.29ubuntu1, 1.29ubuntu2), gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), init-system-helpers:amd64 (1.29ubuntu1, 1.29ubuntu2), qtbase5-dev-tools:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), plasma-workspace:amd64 (4:5.5.5.2-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), libpackagekit-glib2-16:amd64 (0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1, 0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.1), libimage-magick-perl:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), libqt5test5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2, 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.2), libxml2-utils:amd64 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1, 2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1), libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.2.10ubuntu1, 1.2.12~ubuntu16.04.1), libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3, 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2, 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.2), libimage-magick-q16-perl:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), qml-module-org-kde-activities:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu1, 5.22.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa3), apturl-common:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu11, 0.5.2ubuntu11.1), kicad-library:amd64 (4.1.0-alpha+201605221502+634~2~ubuntu16.04.1, 4.1.0-alpha+201606072116+951~2~ubuntu16.04.1), libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), libqt5opengl5-dev:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), apt:amd64 (1.2.10ubuntu1, 1.2.12~ubuntu16.04.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), kwin-data:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), kamera:amd64 (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1, 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1.1), snapd:amd64 (2.0.3, 2.0.5), binutils:amd64 (2.26-8ubuntu2, 2.26-8ubuntu2.1), libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), libkf5activities5:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu1, 5.22.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa3), libqt5dbus5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), libqt5widgets5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), udev:amd64 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), plasma-desktop:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa3), command-not-found-data:amd64 (0.3ubuntu16.04, 0.3ubuntu16.04.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.2.10ubuntu1, 1.2.12~ubuntu16.04.1), libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), libudev1:i386 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), plasma-desktop-data:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa3), libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), libqt5concurrent5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1), imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), libqt5gui5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), apturl-kde:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu11, 0.5.2ubuntu11.1), libpam-kwallet4:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), libpam-kwallet5:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), adwaita-icon-theme:amd64 (3.18.0-2ubuntu3, 3.18.0-2ubuntu3.1), python3-commandnotfound:amd64 (0.3ubuntu16.04, 0.3ubuntu16.04.1), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1), qt5-qmake:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), dmidecode:amd64 (3.0-2, 3.0-2ubuntu0.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), systemd-sysv:amd64 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), libkf5screen-bin:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 (1.14.9-
0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.15.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu5, 229-4ubuntu6), libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), dh-python:amd64 (2.20151103ubuntu1, 2.20151103ubuntu1.1), apt-utils:amd64 (1.2.10ubuntu1, 1.2.12~ubuntu16.04.1), kwin-x11:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), qtbase5-dev:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), libkwin4-effect-builtins1:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 (1.8.0-1, 1.8.1-1~ubuntu1), libxml2:amd64 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1, 2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1), libxml2:i386 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1, 2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1), gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 (0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1, 0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.1), command-not-found:amd64 (0.3ubuntu16.04, 0.3ubuntu16.04.1), imagemagick-common:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1), kscreen:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.2.10ubuntu1, 1.2.12~ubuntu16.04.1), kicad:amd64 (4.1.0-alpha+201605222346+6820~44~ubuntu16.04.1, 4.1.0-alpha+201606071201+6887~45~ubuntu16.04.1), apport-kde:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1), libqt5network5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.0-1, 1.8.1-1~ubuntu1), libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (1.8.0-1, 1.8.1-1~ubuntu1), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.1-0ubuntu2, 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1), kde-spectacle:amd64 (15.12.3-0ubuntu1, 15.12.3-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04~ppa2), ubuntu-mono:amd64 (14.04+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1, 14.04+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu2), libpowerdevilcore2:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), kwin-common:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1, 4:5.6.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1), libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1), bash-completion:amd64 (1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1, 1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1), libqt5sql5-mysql:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7, 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1)
Remove: kactivities:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu1), libkwinglutils7:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1), libkf5screen6:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2016-06-08  12:00:52
```

---

## Persistent Issues:

Chromium keeps asking me to make it my default browser. The background image in the logon screen keeps zoomed in.

---

## New Issues:

Now the background image in the logon screen will never render properly (not even when entering the password correctly), and the animation of the KDE logo has been changed (i.e. it was originally from top to bottom with transparent bars overriding each other, now it is from right to left with static bars). When moving to a different virtual desktop, a black box of around one quarter of the screen will display in the top left corner.