# Woobly windows effect not working on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, kubuntu

[Earlier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776398/qtbase5-installation-modified-graphics-significantly) I had a problem in which the graphics and some important functions of the system stopped working properly. Now, simple things like the woobly windows effect, or the traslucent effect don't work.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: if the problem didn't get solved, accepting harms the question. less people will be interested in it

Comment: @Anwar The problem was partially solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very disappointed with Plasma 5 environment. I have the same problem of "Hans" and the desktop crashes regularly.
So far I have found that ALT +SHIFT +F12 restore the settings (Thanks to this [bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344319)) in the "System Setting" the shortcut is defined as "Suspend Compositing" (some more info present in the Kubuntu forum "[PlasmaShell and Compositing Problems](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?70022-PlasmaShell-and-Compositing-Problems)" )

Comment: Worked like a charm, is there a permanent fix for this? Do you recommend the kernel downgrade proposed in the link you provided as a reference?